# Как отсортировать массив json по его элементу?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, discord.py, dict

**Как отсортировать массив json в python?**

В данном случае я пытаюсь реализовать команду **leaders** (discord.py) в которой нужно отсортировать json-массив **"users"** по int-элементу **level**.

**Массив:**

```
{"947336492487942174": {"experience": 6, "level": 1, "need_xp": 10}, "702338551806951466": {"experience": 7, "level": 3, "need_xp": 10}, "853231575332552704": {"experience": 8, "level": 6, "need_xp": 10}}
```

**Сам код:**

```
@client.command(aliases=['l', 'лидеры'])
async def leaders(ctx):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
      users = json.load(f)
    print(users)
    users = sorted(users, key=lambda x: int(x['level']))
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Лидеры ', colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(randint(5,255), randint(5,255), randint(5,255)))
    for user in users:
      level = int(users[f'{user.id}']['level'])
      embed.add_field(name=user, value=f'Уровень: **{level}**')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что у вас словарь вложенный, а написанная вами сортировка этого не учитывает.

Для решения достаточно получить внутренние словари и уже тогда сортировать по значению поля `level`:

```
users = {"947336492487942174": {"experience": 6, "level": 3, "need_xp": 10},
         "702338551806951466": {"experience": 7, "level": 1, "need_xp": 10},
         "853231534433255270": {"experience": 8, "level": 4, "need_xp": 10}}

print(sorted(users.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['level']))
```

Вывод:

> ```
> [('702338551806951466', {'experience': 7, 'level': 1, 'need_xp': 10}), 
>  ('947336492487942174', {'experience': 6, 'level': 3, 'need_xp': 10}), 
>  ('853231534433255270', {'experience': 8, 'level': 4, 'need_xp': 10})]
> ```

Comment: Тогда как их получить и как с ними работать?

Comment: @QuL1ux так в ответе есть код

Comment: Данным массив в вопросе всё время изменяется, в нём могут быть другие значения и больше строк, а не 3

Comment: @QuL1ux вы серьезно? этот код работает для словаря с любым количеством элементов...

Comment: а да, я просто ошибся. Возникла ещё одна проблема на строке `level = int(users[f'...`: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: @QuL1ux так переведите ошибку, это совсем уже базовые вещи. и если возник новый вопрос, то создайте его отдельно, к сортировке это никак не относится

Comment: А возможно ли как-то отсортировать по двум критериям? В первую очередь по 'level', а во вторую очередь по 'experience'