# TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str в цикле for

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словари

Я пытался создать команду **leaders** (discord.py), у меня уже есть отсортированный массив с пользователями, но я не могу использовать данные в нём

**Пример массива:**

```
{"702338551806951466": {"experience": 45, "level": 3, "need_xp": 70}}
```

**Сам код:**

```
@client.command(aliases=['l', 'лидеры'])
async def leaders(ctx):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as f:
      users = json.load(f)
    users = sorted(users.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['level'], reverse=True)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Лидеры ', colour=discord.Colour.from_rgb(randint(5,255), randint(5,255), randint(5,255)))
    for user in users:
      level = user['level'] #ошибка тут
      embed.add_field(name=user.name, value=f'Уровень: **{level}**')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

**Ошибка:**

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

**Как можно получить элемент массива в цикле? И как получить название массива, то-есть id человека?**

Comment: Вы бы хоть какие-то выводы сделали с [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1483878/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2-json-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d1%83/1483883#1483883) вопроса...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `level = user['level']` поменяйте обращение на `user[1]['level']`

А чтобы получить `id`, то обращайтесь к `user[0]`

Выше вы отсортировали список ключ-значений словаря по ключу `level` у значения, поэтому в `users` у вас теперь список из кортежей вида `(<ключ>, <значение>)`, пример элемента в `users`:

```
('702338551806951466', {'experience': 45, 'level': 3, 'need_xp': 70})
```

Answer (score 2):

```
users = {"947336492487942174": {"experience": 6, "level": 3, "need_xp": 10},
         "702338551806951466": {"experience": 7, "level": 1, "need_xp": 10},
         "853231534433255270": {"experience": 8, "level": 4, "need_xp": 10}}
users = sorted(users.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['level'], reverse=True)
# 1
for id_user, skill_user in users:
    print(f"{id_user} Уровень: ** {skill_user['level']} **")
# 2
for index, user in enumerate(users, 1):
    id_user, skill_user = user
    print(f"{index} {id_user} Уровень: ** {skill_user['level']} **")
```

Comment: `for index, (id_user, skill_user) in enumerate(users, 1):` второй вариант можно еще так :)